# PHP Optimizing Nested Loop

Tags: php

Admittedly, I'm not very strong with PHP. I have a situation where I need to check if a given user is authorized to visit a given webpage.

A user can potentially have zero or more roles. To do this, I setup three tables:

1. User
2. Role
3. UserRole

Role references user. UserRole references both User and Role.

A webpage is will always have a parent menu to reference. Think of it in the case of a dropdown menu where the top-level menu item does not represent a webpage, but the child menu items do.

To do this, I setup 3 tables:

1. Menu
2. MenuItem
3. MenuItemRole

Menu and MenuItem both have a name. MenuItem references Menu. And MenuItemRole references both Menu and MenuItem.

Now I created a function that has the following arguments: *menuName*, *menuItemName*, and *userId*.

As far as my business logic is concerned, I am doing the following:

1. get all of the user's roles by the given *userId*
2. get the menu id by the given *menuName*
3. get the menu item id by the given *menuItemName*
4. get all of the menu item roles by the results of #2 and #3
5. loop over all the records from #1 and #4 until a match is found

This is the code that I setup:

```php
public static function authorizeView($menuName, $menuItemName, $userId) {
    if (!$menuName || $menuItemName || $userId) {
        throw new Exception("Unauthorized");
    }

    // get all of the user's roles
    $filters = array();
    $filters["UserId"] = $userId;
    $userRoles = UserRoleService::query($filters);
    if ($userRoles["total"] === 0) {
        return false;
    }

    // get the menu id
    $filters = array();
    $filters["MenuName"] = $menuName;
    $menus = MenuService::query($filters);
    if ($menus["total"] === 0) {
        return false;
    }
    $menuId = $menus["records"][0]["MenuId"];

    // get the menu item id
    $filters = array();
    $filters["MenuItemName"] = $menuItemName;
    $menuItems = MenuItemService::query($filters);
    if ($menuItems["total"] === 0) {
        return false;
    }
    $menuItemId = $menuItems["records"][0]["MenuItemId"];

    // get the menu item roles by the menu/menu item
    $filters = array();
    $filters["MenuId"] = $menuId;
    $filters["MenuItemId"] = $menuItemId;
    $menuItemRoles = MenuItemRoleService::query($filters);
    if ($menuItemRoles["total"] === 0) {
        return false;
    }

    // loop over all of the user roles, if one of the values is in one of the menu item roles, return true
    $authorized = false;
    foreach ($userRoles as $userRole) {
        foreach ($menuItemRoles as $menuItemRole) {
            if ($userRole["RoleId"] === $menuItemRole["RoleId"]) {
                $authorized = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if ($authorized) {
            break;
        }
    }

    // otherwise return false
    return $authorized;
}
```

My first question is: am I architect-ing this right or is it over-engineered?

My second question is: can the nested loop be optimized for readability? Up to that point, I can read everything pretty clearly, but that one section sticks out at me because it is not immediately clear what it is doing.

Comment: This would probably be more appropriate on code review, *if this code works*. As for readability, it could use much improvement, starting with SRP. This method does too much, as noted in your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**About the first question:** It is difficult for me to judge if your architecture is absolutely right or not. As that depends on other logic also related to role/menu (if any). But basically I find it quite similar to the architectures I usually come across, so I don't think there's a problem here.

**About the second question:** Your nested loop can be rewritten as taking the intersection of 2 arrays. Then, the logic would be: "if the user has at least one role associated with the menu and menu item, he will be authorized". I think that's a bit easier to read.

I rewrote your code (from line `// loop over all...`) following the above approach:

```php
$userRoleIds = array_column($userRole, "RoleId");
$menuItemRoleIds = array_column($menuItemRoles, "RoleId");
return !empty(array_intersect($userRoleIds, $menuItemRoleIds));
```